# Vue 3 router: How to split route param into id and slug and make slug optional

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, nuxt3

Im migrating nuxt 2 -> nuxt3 and i have vue router path:

```
{
    name: 'event-id',
    path: '/event/:id(\\d+):slug([\\w-]*)',
    component: () => getComponent(import('../pages/event/[id]')),
},
```

it worked before and gave me id and slug params, if it was link like domain.com/event/1, I had `id: 1` and `slug: ''` or `slug: undefined`, dont remember exacty. But now i have **Missing required param "slug"** error message

Answer (score 0):

Set the param as [optional](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/route-matching-syntax.html#Optional-parameters) by appending `?`

```js
path: '/event/:id(\\d+):slug([\\w-]*)?',
```

Comment: I tried this, it making both id and slug optional, bacause its not separated with /, so i have to have both if i have id

Comment: they are still separate params even if in the same route segment, and the `?` should only affect the one.  I tested this in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-bardeen-h49ddd?file=/src/components/Comp1.vue) and found this to be true.  If you can provide a reproduction of your issue I'd be happy to take a look at it.